# Processing/Java - Having trouble with Class Array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, processing

This is probably a really stupid question but I am having trouble showing more that one copy of my class on the screen. 
I have created an asteroid class that generates and moves an asteroid on the screen. Yet when I try and call multiple versions of this class in my main body, it still only shows one asteroid.

**Main**

```
int lrgAsteroids = 4;
Asteroid[] asteroid = new Asteroid[lrgAsteroids];

void setup() {
  size(800,800);
  for (int i = 0; i < lrgAsteroids; i++) {
      asteroid[i] = new Asteroid();
      asteroid[i].display();
    }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  asteroid[0].move();
  asteroid[1].move();
  for (int i = 0; i < lrgAsteroids; i++) {
    asteroid[i].move();
  }
}
```

**asteroid class.**

```
class Asteroid {
  PImage lrgAsteroid;
  float xpos, ypos;
  float yDirection;
  float xDirection;
  float radians = 0;


  Asteroid() {
    lrgAsteroid = loadImage("largeAsteroid.png");
    xpos = random(0,710);
    ypos = random(0,710);

    int xDir = (int) random(2);
    int yDir = (int) random(2);

    if (xDir == 1) {
      xDirection = 1;
    } else if (xDir == 0) {
      xDirection = -1;
    }

    if (yDir == 1) {
      yDirection = 1;
    } else if (yDir == 0) {
      yDirection = -1;
    }
  }

  void display() {
    image(lrgAsteroid, xpos, ypos);
  }

  void move() {    
     background(0);
     pushMatrix();
     imageMode(CENTER);
     translate(xpos, ypos);
     rotate(radians);
     image(lrgAsteroid, 0, 0);
     popMatrix();

     if (xpos <= 0) {
       xpos = random(750,800);
     } else if (xpos >= 800) {
       xpos = random(0,100);
     }

     if (ypos <= 0) {
       ypos = random(750,800);
     } else if (ypos >= 800) {
       ypos = random(0,100);
     }

     radians += 0.02;
     xpos += xDirection;
     ypos += yDirection;
  }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is very simple. Actually the display is clear, before an asteroid is drawn, because of `background(0);` in the method `move()`. It is sufficient to clear the background at the begin of `draw()`.

Remove `background(0);` from the method `move()`:

```java
Asteroid() {
  // [...]

  void move() {    

     // background(0); <---- DELETE 

     pushMatrix();
     imageMode(CENTER);
     translate(xpos, ypos);
     rotate(radians);
     image(lrgAsteroid, 0, 0);
     popMatrix();

     if (xpos <= 0) {
       xpos = random(750,800);
     } else if (xpos >= 800) {
       xpos = random(0,100);
     }

     if (ypos <= 0) {
       ypos = random(750,800);
     } else if (ypos >= 800) {
       ypos = random(0,100);
     }

     radians += 0.02;
     xpos += xDirection;
     ypos += yDirection;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that somehow all the instances that your create get the same xDir and yDir or same xpos and ypos , can you print it so you can see if that's the problem ?

```
void setup() {
size(800,800);
for (int i = 0; i < lrgAsteroids; i++) {
  asteroid[i] = new Asteroid();
  // add these please to see what happens
  System.out.println(asteroid[i].xDirection+" "+asteroid[i].yDirection);

 }
}

void draw() {
 background(0);
 asteroid[0].move();
 asteroid[1].move();
 for (int i = 0; i < lrgAsteroids; i++) {
   asteroid[i].move();
   // add these please to see what happens
   System.out.println(asteroid[i].xpos+" "+asteroid[i].ypos);
 }
```